# how can I remove special characters

Tags: python

How can I remove the special characters from the list

`[('testa.dom1.int', [], ['192.168.1.1'])]", ('testb.dom1.int', [], ['192.168.1.2'])]`

what I want as result = `[(testa.dom1.int, 192.168.1.1), (testb.dom1.int, 192.168.1.2)`

```
import os
import socket
import subprocess
import dns.resolver
import string

results_file = open("results.txt", "w")
my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
my_resolver.nameservers = ['192.168.1.2']

ip_list = []
name_list = []
strp_list = []

for ip in range(1, 5):
    ip_list.append('192.168.1.' + str(ip))

with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:
    for ip in ip_list:
        response = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-W", "1", ip],
                        stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait()
        if response:
            print(ip + ' down')
        else:
            name = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
            name_list.append(name)
            **strp = str(name_list).replace("[],", '')** # is removing the []
            strp_list.append(strp)
            name_list = strp_list.copy()
            print("3 list:", name_list)
            str(name_list).replace("['", '')
            print("4 list:", name_list)
            print("5 list:", strp_list)            
            name_list = strp_list.copy()
            print("6 list:", name_list)           

results_file.close()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: just compare it with another list of chars you want to remove

Comment: You should not try to do this, and you should not try to make a string in first place. Instead, you should treat the list data that you got *as a list*. It's important that you understand variable types, and that you understand the difference between the *representation of* a thing, and the thing itself.

Comment: Unfortunately the result you want is not a python expression. Did you mean: `[('testa.dom1.int', '192.168.1.1'), ('testb.dom1.int', '192.168.1.2')]`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to display the contents of a list with some kind of special formatting, do not try to "fix" the natural string representation of the list. Instead, write your own code to build the string, inserting data from the list in the appropriate places. You can use string formatting to make this easier.

I assume you have the following actual data structure:

```
my_data = [
    ('testa.dom1.int', [], ['192.168.1.1']),
    ('testb.dom1.int', [], ['192.168.1.2'])
]
```

and you want to create the exact string:

```
goal = "[(testa.dom1.int, 192.168.1.1), (testb.dom1.int, 192.168.1.2)]"
```

First, let's make a function that can get the right string for each element of `my_data`, and then we can put them together. So we want to turn e.g. `('testa.dom1.int', [], ['192.168.1.1'])` into `"(testa.dom1.int, 192.168.1.1)"`. We'll receive one argument, which is a tuple; to create the string, we'll *unpack* the tuple into separate variables, then pull the IP address string out of the nested list, then use string formatting to build the complete string. That looks like:

```
def process_site(entry):
    domain_name, empty_list, ip_list = entry
    ip = ip_list[0]
    return f'({domain_name}, {ip})'
```

Now we can iterate over `my_data` to produce the corresponding text for each element, and use the `join` method of a `', '` string to put them together; and finally put the `[]` around the outside using string formatting again. So:

```
contents = [process_site(entry) for entry in my_data]
joined = ', '.join(contents)
goal = f'[{joined}]'
```